# Error finding the nearest place with Facebook SDK (iOS)

Tags: ios, facebook-graph-api, swift2, facebook-sdk-4.0

In this part of my app, the user is logged into Facebook and the current location is retrieved using a CLLocationManager correctly. The next step is to search for the nearest place, yet when I do I get this error...

> Error Domain=com.facebook.sdk.core Code=8 "We couldn't determine the
>   coordinates of this location. Check if your latitude and longitude are
>   in range, and verify the format of the location."

Here are two methods, one searches and the other posts a sample place with a set place ID to the current user's feed (which works just fine), yet obviously I want the place ID to be the ID of the nearest place. The latitude and longitude are there since I put a breakpoint next to them.

Find nearest place method....

```
func findNearestPlaces() {

    let params = NSMutableDictionary(capacity: 4)

    params.setObject(String(format: "%@, %@", self.latitude!, self.longitude!), forKey: "center")
    params.setObject("place", forKey: "type")
    params.setObject("100", forKey: "distance")
    params.setObject("name", forKey: "fields")

    let graphRequest = FBSDKGraphRequest.init(graphPath: "/search", parameters: params as [NSObject : AnyObject], HTTPMethod: "GET")
    graphRequest.startWithCompletionHandler { (connection, response, error) -> Void in

        if error != nil {
            print(error)
        }

        else if let response = response {

            print(response)
        }
    }

}
```

Check in method with dummy place ID (like I said, working, but just included it for further reference)

```
func checkIn() {

    if FBSDKAccessToken.currentAccessToken() != nil {

        if FBSDKAccessToken.currentAccessToken().hasGranted("publish_actions") {

            let parameterDictionary = NSMutableDictionary()
            parameterDictionary.setObject("This is a test, I'm building an app!", forKey: "message")
            parameterDictionary.setObject("110503255682430", forKey: "place") //TEST <<!

            let graphRequest = FBSDKGraphRequest.init(graphPath: "/me/feed", parameters: parameterDictionary as [NSObject : AnyObject], HTTPMethod: "POST")

            graphRequest.startWithCompletionHandler({ (connection, result, error) -> Void in

                if error != nil {
                    print(error)
                }

                else {

                    print(result)
                }
            })
        }
    }

    else {

        let loginManager = FBSDKLoginManager()
        loginManager.logInWithPublishPermissions(["publish_actions"], fromViewController: self, handler: { (result, error) -> Void in

        if error != nil {
            print(error)
        }

        else if let result = result {
            print(result)

        }
        })
    }
}
```

Any ideas? I'm so close! Like always the help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: can you please put the location you are getting to test?

Comment: and what this is for? `params.setObject("name", forKey: "fields")`

Comment: The current location is... ▿ CLLocationCoordinate2D
  - latitude : 37.759755
  - longitude : -122.4270941

Comment: I added the fields parameter because before I was getting an error saying that the fields parameter was lacking although the way I did it likely is not correct since most of the documentation is lacking/out of date. Any ideas on how to fix that? Thank you.

Comment: When I comment out the fields line I get this along with the location error that I posted. >>FBSDKLog: starting with Graph API v2.4, GET requests for //search should contain an explicit "fields" parameter<<

Comment: Okay, this is going to sound silly, but I replaced %@ with %f and now I'm getting something. I'll keep you posted.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to answer my own question... replace %@ with %f and it works perfectly!